# How to update kali without internet connection manually?

Tags: upgrade, kali-linux

I have installed kali linux in virtual box with a windows host, and when I try to update kali it completes 5-10 packages and aborts saying connection failed. I have a slow connection and want to get a manual update and to know how to install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since Kali is based on Debian, you can use `apt-offline`: [Ways to update Ubuntu (debian-based distros) offline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89152/ways-to-update-ubuntu-debian-based-distros-offline)