# How to upgrade Debian 10 to Debian 11 without internet?

Tags: debian, dist-upgrade, apt-offline

In the future I have to upgrade several Debian 10 systems to Debian 11.
The problem is: The systems have no access to the internet.

What options do I have to upgrade the system?

After some research, I found apt-offline which seemed to be suitable for this task.
I tried apt-offline on a fully updated example Debian 10 in the following manner:

offline system:

1. change the /etc/apt/sources.list from buster (Debian 10) to bullseye (Debian 11)
2. create apt-offline.sig with : `sudo apt-offline set --upgrade-type dist-upgrade apt-offline.sig`

on the online system:

3. create bundle.zip with `apt-offline get --bundle bundle.zip apt-offline.sig`

on the offline system:

4. install bundle with : `sudo apt-offline install bundle.zip`

This does not work. apt tries to fetch packages from the internet when apt-get dist-upgrade is performed and the bundle.zip is also only 27Mb big.

It doesn't look like apt-offline is suitable for doing Debian release upgrades.

Is there any other method to perform an offline release upgrade from debian 10 to debian 11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to update Ubuntu (debian-based distros) offline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89152/ways-to-update-ubuntu-debian-based-distros-offline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade a Debian installation using downloadable images, *e.g.* [the `amd64` DVD image](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-dvd/). You don’t need to re-install the operating system to use these; they can be used to upgrade an existing setup in the same way as repositories hosted on the Internet. The release notes contain [detailed instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#cdroms); basically, you need to download the image, mount it, then run

```
apt-cdrom add
```

to have it taken into account.

You can then run `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` as usual.

If the images you downloaded don’t contain all the packages necessary to upgrade your specific systems, you can create [images containing all of Debian](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/jigdo-bd/) using Jigdo. Alternatively, you can remove the non-upgradable packages temporarily, upgrade to Debian 11, then use `apt-offline` to install them again.